# Cakephp routing not work as my need?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My url is:

```
http://localhost/rehabhousing/homes/articles/3/terms-conditions
```

now we routing my url

```
http://localhost/rehabhousing/terms-conditions
```

but the url is create dynamicall

Answer (score 0):

at last i can do

```
$routes->connect('/terms-conditions/*', ['controller' => 'Homes','action' => 'articles',3,'terms-conditions']);
```